# Как с помощью sed вставить разный текст, в зависимости от того присутствует ли в шаблоне неизвестный текст между известным?

Tags: linux, sed

Как с помощью **sed** вставить разный текст, в зависимости от того присутствует ли в шаблоне неизвестный текст между известным?
Поясняю )
Имеем два варианта
Первый:

```
"pinned_symbol_libs": [
      "неизвестный текст между кавычками",
      "неизвестный текст между кавычками",
      "неизвестный текст между кавычками"
    ]
```

Второй:

```
"pinned_symbol_libs": []
```

Если обнаружиться первый вариант, то вставить между **[** и **"неизвестный текст между кавычками",** свой текст с запятой в конце.
Должно получиться:

```
"pinned_symbol_libs": [
      "свой текст",
      "свой текст",
      "неизвестный текст между кавычками",
      "неизвестный текст между кавычками",
      "неизвестный текст между кавычками"
    ]
```

А если второй вариант, **"свой текст"** без запятой в конце.

```
"pinned_symbol_libs": [
      "свой текст",
      "свой текст"
    ]
```

Comment: А точно данную задачу надо решить через sed? По синтаксису - это yaml, а значит - и в общем-то json. Точно sed? Ты прям уверен?

Comment: @don Rumata
 Да в общем то нет. Мне нужно написать простой скрипт на баш который прописывает библиотеки в кикад (правит два файла) и добавляет их в избранное, дабы руками по менюшкам не лазить. А в этом я не силен. Нагуглил команду sed и пытаюсь сделать с помощью неё. Пока он выглядит вот так:[https://drive.google.com/file/d/183X4fvJTYt2W-cb0TtgAsseJ6tkKZb71/view?usp=sharing]  Я пока в самом начале скриптовых языков и языков вообще, если есть другой способ. буду рад если подскажете. Насколько я знаю bash json не понимает

Comment: Мой скрипт срабатывает только в том случае если библиотеки в избранное ещё не добавлялись иначе из-за отсутствия запятой файл ломается.

Comment: Можно пример файла, который ты прям править хочешь? И путь до него, если Кикад уже установлен.

Comment: @ don Rumata Да конечно:[https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wMpHcinyakGcPVY1ai1yGwrLDqJmjyxK?usp=sharing] Файл sim-lib-table содержит пути до библиотек проекта и sed-ом нормально правится (просто вставляй строчки после  (version 7), вторая строка). UGO.kicad_pro это стартовый файл проекта. Интересующее меня начинается с 392 строки "pinned_symbol_libs":

Comment: Оба файла лежат в директории проекта кикад, в корне. Вот здесь подробнее [https://docs.kicad.org/7.0/ru/kicad/kicad.html]

Comment: Ну `UGO.kicad_pro` - это классический `json`. Так что тут у тебя ОГРОМНЫЙ выбор как добавить нужный тебе элемент в массив (строку после искомой строки). Я бы рекомендовал или `jq` (как пример - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57537190) или `jp` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75880649) `[libraries.pinned_symbol_libs, ['hhhhhhhhh']][]` - рабочий вариант. Обе проги ставятся через `apt` без проблем.

Comment: Благодарю, буду разбираться

Comment: У `jp` есть официальный сайт https://jmespath.org/ с онлайн вариантом проги, чтобы тестить запросы. У `jq` есть https://jqplay.org/

Comment: @donRumata огромное спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету **donRumata** использовал утилиту **jq**.
Получился вот такой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Создаем переменные 
libray_name=$(basename -s .kicad_sym Libray/*.kicad_sym| sed -e ':a' -e '$!N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/","/g' -e s/^/\"/g -e s/$/\"/g)
project_name=$(ls | grep "\.kicad_pro$")
#делаем бэкап файла
sed -i.bak '' $project_name
#Меняем данные в файле
jq '. + {libraries:{pinned_footprint_libs: (.libraries.pinned_footprint_libs), pinned_symbol_libs:(.libraries.pinned_symbol_libs + ['$libray_name'])}}' $project_name.bak > $project_name
```

Скрипт создаёт две переменные; в первую добавляются имена файлов без расширения которые нужно вписать, а во вторую имя файла в который нужно вписать. Далее значения переменных подставляются в команду **jq** которая находит нужный массив и вписывает в него данные и сохраняет их в файл.

Comment: `ls`  лучше заменить на `ls -1` или типа того. Без ничего выхлоп ls иногда выдаёт совершенно не то, что ты ожидаешь - я про формат выхлопа.

Comment: Я бы делал `bak+текущее время` (посмотри в сторону `date`). Да, создаёт мусор при каждом запуске скрипта, но проще будет откатиться в случае факапа.

Comment: По поводу первой строки скрипта: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365367

Comment: @donRumata. Благодарю, по изучаю.